# Erro "Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result" e "Class 'mysqli' not found"

Tags: php, mysqli

Estou desenvolvendo uma API simples utilizando o Slim Framework.

Quando realizo testes locais todas as funções funcionam da maneira como deveriam mas comecei a ter problemas quando subi para uma determinada hospedagem.
Acontece que quando chamo alguma função ela até é achada mas me retorna o seguinte erro:

> Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in.

Já fiz algumas pesquisas antes para tentar solucionar o problema e havia visto a necessidade do 'mysqlnd' ativo na hospedagem mas quando solicito que seja ativo o 'mysqli' é desativado e tenho o seguinte erro:

> Class 'mysqli' not found.

Para que fique mais claro a hospedagem utilizada é a da localweb e a versão do php ativa é a 5. (Tive o mesmo problema com a Hostinger).

Fiquei sem saber o que fazer a principio pois estou iniciando no Php então qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Comment: Essa função eu acho q é a partir da 5.3, ve se lá é .3 ou .2 ainda.

Comment: Ricardo conferi aqui e a versão atual é: PHP Version 5.5.30-1~locaweb+7.12.

Comment: O `mysqli` foi introduzido no `php 5`, já a função `get_result` pertence ao pacote `mysqlnd` que é o driver nativo.

Comment: O módulo `mysqli` esta habilitado no `php.ini`?

Comment: Por favor faça títulos intuitivos. Assim ajudará futuros usuários.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente segundo a própria hospedagem quando eles ativavam 1 o outro era desativado. Felizmente a solução foi até simples: Foi feito o upgrade para o php 5.6 e nele ocorreu tudo bem. Agradeço a ajuda de todos.